# swift Firebase stop duplicate username

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I want to stop duplicate usernames when someone signup, I've did a query to check if the username exists or not to signup a new username. **But!** when i signup with same username with 2 devices at the same time it will create two same usernames! I don't want that to happen.

Here's the query:

```
let username = self.usernameTxt.text



    let userRef = ref.child("users/\(username)")

    userRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.exists() {

            print("Username Already taken!")

        } else {

            self.signupUser() // Create new username

        }


        userRef.removeAllObservers()

    }, withCancel: { error in

        print(error)

    })
```

Database looks like this:
[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WTyH.png)

Here is Firebase RULES:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "(auth != null)",
    ".write": "(auth != null)",

 "users" :{
        ".indexOn": ["username"],
  "$uid":{
          ".read": "(auth != null) ",
          ".write": "(auth != null)",
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

SignupUser() code:

```
func signupUser() {


    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailTxt.text!, password: self.passwordTxt.text!, completion: {
        (user, error) in



        if let error = error {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        if let user = user {



            let changeRequest = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.profileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest.displayName = self.usernameTxt.text!
            changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)


            let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg")

            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profilepic.image!, 0.5)

            let uploadTask = imageRef.put(data!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }

                imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }


                    if let url = url {



                        let userInfo: [String : Any] = ["uid" : user.uid,
                                                        "urlToImage" : url.absoluteString,
                                                        "email" : self.emailTxt.text!,
                                                        "username" : self.usernameTxt.text!,

                                                        ]

                        self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)




                    }


                })



            })

            uploadTask.resume()


        }
    })

}
```

If i removed the username checking before signup it will keep creating same username like duplicate them, Also if there was a checking and there two clients created same username that doesn't exists same time it will create both of them. **What i want is if username exists stop the signup proccess and show alert says username already taken!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to database snapshot you shared, you are storing username at "users/autogeneratedId/\(username)" node.

But according to your code, you are checking for duplicate username at "users/\(username)" node.

So each time if statement returns false as it doesn't find any username at "users/\(username)" node. So else statement is executed.

Possible solution is that you must store username at "users/\(username)" node. Kindly check your insert username code.

Comment: Checking username it works fine and telling me if its exists or not, But the problem is it will create same usernames i dont want clients have same username, So if username exists stop the signup proccess. Also now after creating new user it wont create any info in "users" it only create the authentication email.

Comment: I've edited my question with the code and some info about what i want to do.

Comment: Read "Save data as transactions" section at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write. This would serve your requirements.